# Using a SVG as background in Gtk3 with CSS

Tags: css, svg, gtk3

How can I use a .svg background in gtk+3 using CSS (C code)? When I try this I get the error:

```
(test1:2604): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: teststyle.css:2:40: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/home/mike/gtk/programming/Tests/gtkScalable.svg'
```

My environment is:

- Ubuntu natty (classic no effects mode)
- gtk+-3.2.3,  gdk-pixbuf-2.24.1, pango-1.29.1, atk-2.1.5
- librsvg2-2  2.32.1-0ubuntu3.1
- librsvg2-dev 2.32.1-0ubuntu3.1
- librsvg2-common   2.32.1-0ubuntu3.1
- libpixbufloader-svg.so        in: /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders
- libpixbufloader-svg.so        in: /usr/lib32/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders

This is my test file:

```
/* COMPILE WITH:
   gcc -Wall -o test1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` test1.c
*/

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, 270, 250);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
                     G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default ()
    GdkScreen *screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen,
                                   GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),
                                   GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
    gsize bytes_written, bytes_read;
    const gchar* home = "/home/mike/gtk/programming/Tests/teststyle.css";
    GError *error = 0;

    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (provider,
                                     g_filename_to_utf8(home, strlen(home),
                                                        &bytes_read,
                                                        &bytes_written,
                                                        &error),
                                     NULL);
    g_object_unref (provider);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my style sheet: teststyle.css, and the image I'm using:

http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/0/0/b/11949995711012521407gtk.svg

```
GtkWindow  {
    background-image: url('/home/mike/gtk/programming/Tests/gtkScalable.svg');
}
```

I've also tried updating the cache with this command as suggested on some other sites but it didn't work and actually corrupted some of my .c files and I had to start over:

```
gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache
```

**UPDATE:** I tried running this under Unity and still it doesn't work. I also tried it when I had the Gorilla theme (Gtk2-engines) selected which uses .svg images itself and still no luck. Do I need Gtk3-engines ?? I have seen examples on sugar-toolkit-gtk3. But it's Python and it's not clear how this is being done.

http://erikos.sweettimez.de/2011/12/09/gtk3-code-sprint-rosario-3/

Comment: What are the outputs of the following commands: 1) `file /home/mike/gtk/programming/Tests/gtkScalable.svg` 2) `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders |grep -i Loaderdir` 3) `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders |grep -i svg`?

Comment: (1) SVG Scalable Vector Graphics image
(2) # LoaderDir = /home/mike/gtk/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders
(3) No output, just returns to the prompt.

Comment: From 3) it appears that there is no pixbuf loader for svg in the standard path, i.e in /home/mike/gtk/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders there is no libpixbufloader-svg.so. Have you installed gtk from source?

Comment: Yes I did install gtk from source.

Comment: Ok, one option which you could try is setting `GDK_PIXBUF_MODULEDIR` env variable which requires no changes as such to your environment (i.e. no new installations). Try `export GDK_PIXBUF_MODULEDIR=/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders` & run the application.

Comment: No that didn't work. It still gives the same error message.

Comment: You can try a couple of options. 1) Hack - copy `libpixbufloader-svg.so` to `/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders` 2) Build `libpixbufloader-svg.so` from source with new prefix i.e. one which you used to build & install Gtk

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what happened, maybe I typed the command incorrectly the first time. But I do have libpixbufloader-svg.so When I do: gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders |grep -i svg I get:               "/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so"
"svg" 2 "gdk-pixbuf" "Scalable Vector Graphics" "LGPL"
"image/svg+xml" "image/svg" "image/svg-xml" "image/vnd.adobe.svg+xml" "text/xml-svg" ""
"svg" ""
" <svg" "*    " 100
" <!DOCTYPE svg" "*             " 100

Comment: Please check if the library is in the loader directory i.e. svg loader is in the path of `gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders |grep -i Loaderdir`. The code which you have is pretty straight forward & I checked on my system, it does seem to work. Do you have multiple installations of gtk? In home directory & `/usr/lib`?

Comment: Success!!, When I installed gtk, I created a dir called gtk in /home/mike where I installed GTK as per the instructions from the manual: developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-building.html I'm not sure why, but libpixbufloader-svg.so was not created in that dir. So I copied it from /usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders to my install dir. Then I edited loaders.cache to include the svg portion (two comments ago) with the correct path. Thank you very much!